# Configurar SessionFactory Hibernate 5.2

Tags: java, hibernate

Alguém sabe de algum tutorial ou consegue me dar um exemplo de configuração para classe HibernateUtil.java para versão 5.2 do hibernate?
Já vi algumas configurações, inclusive na documentação. Porém ainda estou com dúvidas por ser novo em java e hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta não contém muitos detalhes, mas acho que sei o que te aflige:

Esta classe utilitária deve ser a Fábrica de persistência com o banco de dados, onde ela receberá uma unidade de persistência do `persistence.xml`:
Ex01:
a questão do nome da classe é opcional, como uso a especificação JPA, o nome da minha classe é `JPAUtil` a sua se chama `HibernateUtil`.

```
package br.com.financas.util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    public class JPAUtil {

        private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("financas");

        public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        }

    }
```

Note que "financas" é o nome da persistence-unit do arquivo persistence.xml;

a seguir temos uma classe de execução, onde instancio objetos e faço transações com o banco:
Ex02:
note que busco a instância do `EntityManager` através da classe `JPAUtil`, nesse trecho do código: `(EntityManager manager = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();`);

```
package br.com.financas.util;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import br.com.financas.modelo.Conta;
import br.com.financas.modelo.Movimentacao;
import br.com.financas.modelo.TipoMovimentacao;

public class PopulaBanco {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManager manager = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();

        manager.getTransaction().begin();

        Conta conta1 = new Conta();
        Conta conta2 = new Conta();
        Conta conta3 = new Conta();
        Conta conta4 = new Conta();
        Conta conta5 = new Conta();

        conta1.setBanco("001 - BANCO DO BRASIL");
        conta1.setNumero("16987-8");
        conta1.setAgencia("6543-0");
        conta1.setTitular("Maria dos Santos");

        conta2.setBanco("237 - BANCO BRADESCO");
        conta2.setNumero("86759-1");
        conta2.setAgencia("1745");
        conta2.setTitular("Paulo Roberto Souza");

        conta3.setBanco("341 - BANCO ITAU UNIBANCO");
        conta3.setNumero("46346-3");
        conta3.setAgencia("4606");
        conta3.setTitular("Antonio Duraes");

        conta4.setBanco("033 - BANCO SANTANDER");
        conta4.setNumero("12345-6");
        conta4.setAgencia("9876-0");
        conta4.setTitular("Leandra Marques");

        conta5.setBanco("104 - CAIXA ECONOMICA FEDERAL");
        conta5.setNumero("987654-3");
        conta5.setAgencia("1234");
        conta5.setTitular("Alexandre Duarte");

        // persistindo as contas
        manager.persist(conta1);
        manager.persist(conta2);
        manager.persist(conta3);
        manager.persist(conta4);
        manager.persist(conta5);

        // Movimentacoes da conta1
        Movimentacao movimentacao1 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao2 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao3 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao4 = new Movimentacao();

        movimentacao1.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao1.setDescricao("Conta de luz - ABRIL/2012");
        movimentacao1.setValor(new BigDecimal("135"));
        movimentacao1.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.SAIDA);
        movimentacao1.setConta(conta1);

        manager.persist(movimentacao1);

        movimentacao2.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao2.setDescricao("Almoco no Restaurante - AGOSTO/2012");
        movimentacao2.setValor(new BigDecimal("175.80"));
        movimentacao2.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.SAIDA);
        movimentacao2.setConta(conta1);

        manager.persist(movimentacao2);

        movimentacao3.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao3.setDescricao("Aluguel - MAIO/2012");
        movimentacao3.setValor(new BigDecimal("680.00"));
        movimentacao3.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.ENTRADA);
        movimentacao3.setConta(conta1);

        manager.persist(movimentacao3);

        movimentacao4.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao4.setDescricao("Salario - FEVEREIRO/2012");
        movimentacao4.setValor(new BigDecimal("3830.68"));
        movimentacao4.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.ENTRADA);
        movimentacao4.setConta(conta1);

        manager.persist(movimentacao4);

        // Movimentacoes da conta2
        Movimentacao movimentacao5 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao6 = new Movimentacao();

        movimentacao5.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao5.setDescricao("Conta de telefone - SETEMBRO/2011");
        movimentacao5.setValor(new BigDecimal("168.27"));
        movimentacao5.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.SAIDA);
        movimentacao5.setConta(conta2);

        manager.persist(movimentacao5);

        movimentacao6.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao6.setDescricao("Aniversario - MAIO/2011");
        movimentacao6.setValor(new BigDecimal("200"));
        movimentacao6.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.ENTRADA);
        movimentacao6.setConta(conta2);

        manager.persist(movimentacao6);

        // Movimentacoes da conta3
        Movimentacao movimentacao7 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao8 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao9 = new Movimentacao();

        movimentacao7.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao7.setDescricao("Lanche - JULHO/2011");
        movimentacao7.setValor(new BigDecimal("28.50"));
        movimentacao7.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.SAIDA);
        movimentacao7.setConta(conta3);

        manager.persist(movimentacao7);

        movimentacao8.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao8.setDescricao("Presente - DEZEMBRO/2011");
        movimentacao8.setValor(new BigDecimal("49.99"));
        movimentacao8.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.SAIDA);
        movimentacao8.setConta(conta3);

        manager.persist(movimentacao8);

        movimentacao9.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao9.setDescricao("Bonus - JANEIRO/2012");
        movimentacao9.setValor(new BigDecimal("2000"));
        movimentacao9.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.ENTRADA);
        movimentacao9.setConta(conta3);

        manager.persist(movimentacao9);

        // Movimentacoes da conta4
        Movimentacao movimentacao10 = new Movimentacao();

        movimentacao10.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao10.setDescricao("Carnaval - MARCO/2012");
        movimentacao10.setValor(new BigDecimal("765.20"));
        movimentacao10.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.SAIDA);
        movimentacao10.setConta(conta4);

        manager.persist(movimentacao10);

        // Movimentacoes da conta5
        Movimentacao movimentacao11 = new Movimentacao();
        Movimentacao movimentacao12 = new Movimentacao();

        movimentacao11.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao11.setDescricao("Salario - ABRIL/2012");
        movimentacao11.setValor(new BigDecimal("2651.90"));
        movimentacao11.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.ENTRADA);
        movimentacao11.setConta(conta5);

        manager.persist(movimentacao11);

        movimentacao12.setData(Calendar.getInstance());
        movimentacao12.setDescricao("Bonus - JANEIRO/2012");
        movimentacao12.setValor(new BigDecimal("1000"));
        movimentacao12.setTipoMovimentacao(TipoMovimentacao.ENTRADA);
        movimentacao12.setConta(conta5);

        manager.persist(movimentacao12);

        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        manager.close();
    }

}
```

o arquivo `persistence.xml`:

Ex03:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- unidade de persistencia com o nome financas -->
    <persistence-unit name="financas">

        <!-- Implementação do JPA, no nosso caso Hibernate -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <!-- Aqui são listadas todas as entidades -->
        <class>br.com.financas.modelo.Conta</class>
        <class>br.com.financas.modelo.Movimentacao</class>

        <properties>

            <!-- Propriedades JDBC -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/financas" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="javax321" />

            <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Ok, acredito que entendi em parte.
No caso dos teus exemplos, vi que usa o JPA, como estou utilizando Maven, iria mudar muita coisa?
Algumas outras dúvidas que tinha, você conseguiu me responder. Entretanto a minha principal questão aqui seria como configurar a fabrica de persistencia do Hibernate 5.2, pois vi que nesta versão ficou diferente o código da classe.

Comment: Na configuração do Maven não muda nada, pois lá só diz quais dependências vc está usando, por exemplo, eu uso a especificação do JPA, mas a implementação do Hibernate 5.3.9 (biblioteca) na pasta lib do projeto, no caso do Maven vc só escreve no pom.xml a versão da biblioteca que vc gostaria de usar, por exemplo Hibernate 5.2 q ele vai buscar no repositório de dependências.

Comment: A questão da fábrica de persistência... vc está usando as classes do próprio hibernate, incluindo o hibernate.cfg.xml? Neste caso, realmente precisa de uma configuração específica pra esta classe, e posso publicá-la, porém usar essa configuração é desaconselhada, para evitar o alto acoplamento. seu código ficaria muito dependente da implementação do hibernate, caso algum dia vc queira mudar de provedor, para o EclipseLink por exemplo, seria uma dor de cabeça imensa.

Comment: ah, poste suas classes e arquivos de configuração.